# For what kind of queries is In-Memory OLTP faster in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have been doing research on In-Memory OLTP that comes with SQL-Server 2014. I am reading many blogs, whitepapers and available presentations around the web.

So far, i have found only one scenario where In-Memory OLTP is rapid fast than disk-based tables. Insert operation in in-memory table was almost 100 times faster than on disk-based tables.

I haven't found any other queries where in-memory oltp is faster. I have tried Select, Update, Join and Where queries on both table but couldn't found scenario where In-Memory OLTP was better.

It would be great if you could suggest me some queries or scenarios.

Following are two select queries and all tables used in query have 1.4 Million Rows.

1) In-memory (Both the tables are disk-based)

```
SELECT SD.shoppingcartid
,SD.shoppingcartname
,sr.Createdate
,sr.TotalPrice
,Rank() OVER (
    ORDER BY TOTALPRICE DESC
    ) AS PriceRank
FROM shoppingcart SR
JOIN shoppingcartdetail SD ON (SD.shoppingcartid = SR.shoppingcartId)
WHERE (
        (
            TOTALPRICE > 50000
            AND CREATEDATE >= GETDATE()
            )
        OR (
            TOTALPRICE / 3 < 50000
            AND CREATEDATE <= GETDATE()
            )
        )
ORDER BY TotalPrice DESC
```

**Time Taken : 8 Seconds to return 0.7 Million Rows**

2) In-Memory (Both tables are In-Memory table)

```
SELECT SD.shoppingcartid
    ,SD.shoppingcartname
    ,sr.CreatedDate
    ,sr.TotalPrice
    ,Rank() OVER (
        ORDER BY TOTALPRICE DESC
        ) AS PriceRank
FROM shoppingcart_reg SR
JOIN shoppingcartdetail_regular SD ON (SD.shoppingcartid = SR.shoppingcartId)
WHERE (
        (
            TOTALPRICE > 50000
            AND CREATEdDATE >= GETDATE()
            )
        OR (
            TOTALPRICE / 3 < 50000
            AND CREATEdDATE <= GETDATE()
            )
        )
ORDER BY TotalPrice DESC
```

**Time Taken : 11 seconds to return 0.7 Million Rows**

Comment: I'd like to see how those measurements were performed. You can see the difference even with a simple select by primary key.

Comment: Basically I observed time taken by each query to execute in SSMS. I observed it with 400K rows. Select statement for In-memory table and disk-based table both took 2 seconds.

Comment: Selecting 400k rows is not OLTP. Most of the time spent will be serialization, network, deserialization and SSMS UI overheads. Try selecting `count(*)` to only copy one row.

Comment: I did try that and for both In-memory table and and Disk-based table it took few milliseconds for 1.4 Million rows.

Comment: Try OLTP stuff. Not millions of rows. Select a row by primary key 1M times in a loop: `select @dummyVar = DummyCol from T where ID = @someID`. The var is there to not send output to SSMS. Compile this, including the loop, into a procedure. If you don't find any meaningful difference here you are doing something more fundamental wrong.

Comment: Responding to your edit: With such a complicated query you are targeting even more weaknesses of Hekaton. Hekaton has restricted query plans. No hash joins or hash aggregation. I believe only loop joins. You ask: Why is Heakton not faster? Yet, you target Hekatons weaknesses. I don't know how to help you with this behavior. Follow up on my suggestions.

Comment: If you don't mind It would be great if you can provide the select query that is faster in hekaton.

Comment: I did. Follow up on my suggestions.

Comment: Also look into natively compiled stored procedures rather than just plain old interpreted TSQL, that's where the in-memory stuff starts to get really quick.